# Combination probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a list of integers [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7]
I have to select 3 numbers at random. What is the probability that atleast one of the selected number is 6?
Please help on how to proceed with this query. I have tried combination formula but still not able to arrive the result. The result for this is 0.745454545454

Answer (score 1):

As this looks like a homework, and you don't ask for the answer but only help for how to proceed, I would like to give only an idea.

You can find the probability of not having 6 selected, and then subtracting this probability from 1.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is not part of homework but a part of programming practice question I was trying on hackathon for self learning. :)  I got the mistake I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

First compute the probability of the Complementary event when no 6 is selected. Then subtract this value from 1.

The solution is:

```
1 - (combination(8,3) / combination(12,3)) = 0.7454545454545
```

Comment: Thank you!! I did the same but my bad.. did calculation error for 12c3.